# Is there a Zend_Queue_Adapter_Beanstalkd?

Tags: php, zend-framework, beanstalkd

Before going to write my own Adapter I am looking for an existing Zend_Queue Adapter that supports beanstalkd.

Is there a Open Source Adapter/Implementation somewhere for Beanstalkd in the Zend Framework?

So far I could not find something on the web.

Thanks to everyone for reading or answering!

Comment: For testing purpose I quickly put an Adapter based on Pheanstalk together, if case someone is interested in it: https://github.com/ifavo/favo_Queue_Adapter_Pheanstalk

Comment: favo_Queue_Adapter_Pheanstalk looks pretty good. Sicne the ZF queue doesn't support the extras that Beanstalkd/Pheanstalk supports, it's incomplete. Thats why I've tended to write a simple wrapper around Pheanstalk, and then use it almost directly.